# Custom verification of password in ASP.NET SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I would like to verfiy a password, stored by SimpleMembership Provider. I have a website, made with ASP.NET 4.0 MVC using SimpleMembership and a backend admin tool made with ASP.NET WebForms 4.0. Due to the fact, that SimpleMembership needs ASP.NET 4.5, i would like to verify the login password by myself instead of updating the whole admin website to v4.5.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just call `Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)`

Comment: Anyway, solved it with System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword

Comment: Note that the Membership class is in the System.Web.Security namespace.  This solution is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thanks!